# normal microfarad reading in humans

Tags: power

What would a normal microfarad reading generally be in a human being?   Mine was 0.8 consistantly, but my brother's jumped around between 1.5-3.0, and my mother's reading was around 1.5.

Comment: Come on folks - there is a legitimate question behind this *however* there are obviously some issues being overlooked.  This is a perfect opportunity to *educate* rather than *belittle*.

Comment: What was the method you used in testing for the capacitance of a human?

Answer (score 6):

In [this](http://www.electrostatics.org/images/esa_2008_d1.pdf) paper, an approximate equation was found for the capacitance of a sphere close to a conductive wall. If we assume that you're measuring the capacitance relative to a ground plane this should give some idea of the expected capacitance.

[image]

Where r is the radius and zeta is the ratio of spacing to radius.

If we approximate your mother as a sphere of radius 0.5m 1m from the ground (I have no way of knowing if the resemblance would be close), then e = 8.85E-12, R = 0.5, zeta is 2, and we have:

C ~= 66pF, which is quite a bit less (by more than a factor of 10,000:1) than 0.8uF (. I conclude that your measurements are in error - you're measuring something other than true capacitance.

Edit: You might want to look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodermal_activity) link on electrodermal response. If it is, as I postulated in a comment, mostly skin resistance, then it might be a useful article. A human being is electrically pretty much a fairly conductive bag of salty water and whatever resistance you measure is dominated by the human skin resistance. If you were to (and don't do this on anything alive) prick through the skin you would measure a much lower resistance. You can try it on a steak. When you add salt to water it causes ionic conductivity- pure water is a very good insulator. When I was a kid we measured the resistance of a few people and we found the older aunt of my friend had the highest skin resistance (dry skin) whereas we boys were relatively low in resistance. Being budding engineers we didn't really know any girls so that test was not performed at the time.

This principle is used in one of the measurements (skin conductivity) performed by [polygraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygraph), under the expectation that people who are emotionally upset (as when they are telling a lie) will exhibit physiological responses that can be measured. The actual reliability of polygraphs is in dispute.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP has no concept of capacitance and is just grabbing the probes of a capacitance meter with the hands.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read past the bit beginning "if we approximate your mother...". Still laughing too much ....

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yup, in which case they're probably measuring conductivity mostly. Mom appears to have the most sweaty hands (worried about the measurement?), and Tonya the least. Bro varies, maybe with his activity.

Comment: (+1) For trying to educate instead of belittling (using @chrisstratton words in a comment to the OP) together with lighthearted irony (Now I really feel an urge to grab my advanced calculus books and come up with a better 2nd order mom approximation - this race *will* escalate! ;-) You made my day man! :-D

Comment: fun, when I try and measure my capacitance, (by electro static charging and discharge through x10 scope probe.) I always get ~200 pF.  I wonder if I could change it by some measurable amount by pulling all my extremities in?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Bring it on